# Why is FOR <query> LOOP is so much slower than basic query?

Tags: performance, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-performance

I write very simple plpgsql function which fetches each row from 25mln rows table and compare with prev row. If two sibling rows have equal `"AOGUID"` column they are returned.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_duplicate_zemli() RETURNS setof character varying AS $$
DECLARE
    each_zemla character varying;
    prev_zemla character varying;
BEGIN
    FOR each_zemla IN SELECT "AOGUID" FROM "Zemla" ORDER BY "AOGUID" LOOP
        if (prev_zemla = each_zemla) then
            return next each_zemla;
        end if;
        prev_zemla:= each_zemla;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As I understand it, this function should execute in time near plain query time

```
SELECT "AOGUID" FROM "Zemla" ORDER BY "AOGUID"
```

Unfortunately for me this is not true. Plain query executes in one hour but function executes in 80 hours!

Can anybody explain why the plpgsql function executes so much slower than a plain query and how I can increase performance?

PS:

```
explain SELECT "AOGUID" FROM "Zemla" ORDER BY "AOGUID"
```

> "Index Only Scan using zemla_aoguid_not_unique on "Zemla" 
>   (cost=0.56..3336281.02 rows=25852488 width=37)"

Comment: not relevant, but - why not using window functions? eg `lag` or `lead` for that?..

Comment: Never use a for loop (or PL/pgSQL) if you can do it with plain SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: [Never say never.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397#166397) There are exception to this rule of thumb.

Comment: There are various ways to make this (much) faster. The best answer depends on essential information for [postgresql-performance] questions. Please consider [instructions in the tag info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) Most importantly: your version of Postgres and how many distinct values in `"AOGUID"`. [edit] all defining information into your question, don't hide it in comments. Apart from that, 80x execution time of basic is very odd.

Comment: Are you going to provide additional information or is this question done?

Comment: After research i found that doing vacuum analize + window lag/lead makes it 100+ times faster!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misreading your query, but aren't you just identifying any AOGUID entries that appear more than once in "Zemla"?   Can't that be done as a single grouped query?

```
SELECT "AOGUID" FROM "Zemla"
GROUP BY "AOGUID"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY "AOGUID"
```

Answer (score 0):

check the cost of such qry:

```
explain with pre94 as (
  SELECT "AOGUID", lag("AOGUID") over (ORDER BY "AOGUID") = "AOGUID" test_eq FROM "Zemla"
) 
select "AOGUID" from pre94 where test_eq
```

I believe window function could help you with your task better then self created function.

Also you can reduce qry with `FILTER` if you use [9.4 or later](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html)

Comment: this qry is 50-70 times faster. Can you improve it more? I do not understand your answer about "FILTERR"

```
    select "AOGUID" from (
      SELECT "AOGUID", lag("AOGUID") over (ORDER BY "AOGUID") = "AOGUID" test_eq 
      FROM 
        "Zemla" 
    ) eq
    where test_eq
`

Comment: don't think so - you still need to do the comparison. I did not know you version of postgres, so I put the comment about the feature that comes with 9.4

Comment: I'm using 9.5
`CTE Scan on pre94  (cost=5311965.00..5838177.82 rows=13155320 width=516)"
  Filter: test_eq"
  CTE pre94"
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=4785752.18..5311965.00 rows=26310641 width=37)"
          ->  Sort  (cost=4785752.18..4851528.78 rows=26310641 width=37)"
                Sort Key: "Zemla"."AOGUID""
                ->  Seq Scan on "Zemla"  (cost=0.00..823646.41 rows=26310641 width=37)`